# What is the best option for searching a column with a large amount of text that has been extracted from a PDF in a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, parsing, pdf, search

I am going to have users upload PDF's on my website along with saving a title and description about the PDF. Along with being able to search the title and description for a keyword that the user may input, I want to be able to parse the content of the PDF, store it into my database, and search through the content when a user searches a keyword.

Currently, I am using laravel jobs to accomplish this. I have successfully set up the PHP parser and the job runs well. The issue is, large PDF's obviously create a large amount of text that gets stored in the DB. If there ends up being a lot more users uploading a lot of large PDF's, the database will begin to be very large. Is saving the text in the DB the most efficient way?

Comment: This is the type of exercise meant more for NoSQL or document-store databases.  Consider something like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch), or something similar.

Comment: @D.N. thank you I was thinking someone would suggest that. I will look into ElasticSearch and see which NoSQL provider would work best for my use case scenario.